# How to multiply torch[N,1] and torch[1,N]?

Tags: pytorch, torch

I'd like to calculate a matrix (shape[N,N]) by multiplying 2 torch vectors A(shape[N,1]) and B=A'(shape[1,N]).

When I use `torch.matmul` or `torch.mm`, I got errors or A'A(shape[1,1]).

If A is denoted as
`A = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_N]'`, I want to calculate a matrix C whose (i,j)element is

```
for i in range(N):
     for j in range(N):
       C(i,j) = a_i * a_j
```

I'd like to calculate this quickly. Do you have any ideas?
thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can do something like this :

```py
A = torch.randint(0,5,(5,))
C = (A.view(1, -1) * A.view(-1, 1)).to(torch.float)
```

it produces :

```
tensor([[ 1.,  4.,  3.,  3.,  0.],
        [ 4., 16., 12., 12.,  0.],
        [ 3., 12.,  9.,  9.,  0.],
        [ 3., 12.,  9.,  9.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

which is equivalent to writting :

```py
 D = torch.zeros((5,5))
for i in range(5):
  for j in range(5):
    D[i][j] = A[i] * A[j]
```

which results in :

```py
tensor([[ 1.,  4.,  3.,  3.,  0.],
        [ 4., 16., 12., 12.,  0.],
        [ 3., 12.,  9.,  9.,  0.],
        [ 3., 12.,  9.,  9.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It is exactly what I want to do. It works well and works well. Thank you!!

Comment: no problem. then please accept this as the answer, marking this question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do the following:

```py
import torch
A = torch.randint(0, 5, (3, 2))
B = torch.randint(0, 5, (2, 3))
```

A:

```py
tensor([[1, 3],
        [2, 1],
        [1, 3]])
```

B:

```py
tensor([[1, 0, 3],
        [3, 4, 1]])
```

```py
C = A @ B # python 3.5+
```

C:

```py
tensor([[10, 12,  6],
        [ 5,  4,  7],
        [10, 12,  6]])
```

Comment: I am sorry to be late. Thank you for your help! It is very simple and works well.